# Create html form send a download link to the given email address?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am beginner in web development.

How to create a form that will prompt user to input email address and when user click on the submit button, a download link will be send to the user email address.

Comment: Start writing an minimal example and add that example to your question. Make clear where you encounter problems.

Comment: Yes possible. Now Please start your own research and come back with a specific problem.Please take some time to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so you can learn what types of questions are accepted here, how to write questions, and how to use this site effectively

Comment: You may want to take a look at [EmailJS](http://emailjs.com?src=so), which allows sending email using pre-built templates directly from Javascript [disclaimer - I'm one of the creators]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this simply using PHP.

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
    <input name="message" type="email">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Create a PHP file contact.php.

```
<?php
if($_POST["message"]) {
    mail($_POST['message'], "Subject message","Message to be given in body", "From: your@email.address");
}
?>
```

Comment: Nope, it shows : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING

Comment: You can go through the attached link for details of sending mail in PHP.I think the error you are getting is something related to database. [Reference](http://htmldog.com/techniques/formtoemail/)